# Unknown Exception from IWbemClassObject::Get

Tags: c++, exception, wmi, wbem

I'm trying to retrieve an "ID" from a WMI object right after persisting it.

After building up the instance, I persist it like so:

```
hRes = pSvc->PutInstance(pNewInstance, 0, pCtx, &pResult);
```

All fine and dandy -- it makes it's way into WMI. I then use my `pResult`, which is `IWbemCallResult  **ppCallResult` to call `IWbemCallResult::GetResultObject` like so:

```
IWbemClassObject *ppResultObject = NULL;
hRes = pResult->GetResultObject(WBEM_INFINITE, &ppResultObject);
```

Great. `hRes` is `S_OK` and I appear to have an instance I can retrieve properties on by using `IWbemClassObject::Get`... so I do:

```
VARIANT v;
hRes = ppResultObject->Get(L"ID", 0, &v, 0, 0);
```

**No matter the value that actually exists as the "ID", the value in the VARIANT is 0.** I can't get the other properties I set on it either (they're also 0). I've tried countless variations of this code flow, using `->Get(CComBSTR("ID")...`, `->Get(_bstr_t("ID")...`, etc...

`hRes` is `S_OK` on this Get too.

**If I wrap it all in a `try{}catch(...){}`, it enters the catch, but I don't know how to determine the exception type or why it would fail.** Is there something wrong with this logic or syntax? How can I determine what is going wrong with the `Get(L"ID"...` call?

This is my 3rd week in C++. Please help me not hate it so much.

**Edit:**
Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (as complete and verifiable as it can be without access to my machine and WMI connection):

```
bool 
myNamespace::myWMIWrapper::createUser(User_t * user)
{
    IWbemLocator * pIWbemLocator = NULL;
    HRESULT hRes = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pIWbemLocator);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hRes))
    {   
        BSTR combinedUserName = NULL;
        if (m_username != NULL && m_domainname != NULL)
            combinedUserName =_bstr_t(m_domainname) + _bstr_t(_T("\\")) + _bstr_t(m_username);

        hRes = pIWbemLocator->ConnectServer(
                        m_namespace,      // machine name and namespace
                        combinedUserName, // Userid
                        m_password,       // PW
                        NULL,             // Locale
                        0,                // flags
                        NULL,             // Authority
                        pWCtx,            // Context
                        &pWbemServices );
        }

        if (FAILED(hRes))
        {
            LOGGER << _T("Could not connect to the WMI server. Error code = ") << hRes ;
            pIWbemLocator->Release();
            pIWbemLocator = NULL;   
            CoUninitialize();
            return false;
        }

        hRes = NULL;
        IWbemClassObject *pNewClass = NULL;

        BSTR myClassName = SysAllocString(L"My_Class");
        hRes = pWbemServices->GetObject(myClassName, 0, NULL, &pNewClass, NULL);

        if (FAILED(hRes))
        {
            LOGGER << _T("hRes failed. Couldn't find class using GetObject with class name:");
            LOGGER << className;
        }
        SysFreeString(myClassName);

        if (pNewClass == NULL) {
            LOGGER << _T(" No My_Class class Object was found using query.");
            return false;
        }

        LOGGER << _T("Class definition from WMI is found.");
        IWbemClassObject *pNUser = NULL;

        LOGGER << _T(" Creating an instance of My_Class.");
        hRes = S_OK;

        hRes = pNewClass->SpawnInstance(NULL, &pNUser);
        pNewClass->Release();

        if (FAILED(hRes)) {
            LOGGER << _T(" My_Class Object can not be instansiated.");
            return false;
        }

        LOGGER << _T(" Updating properties of My_Class found by WMI query");

        if (user->getFirstName() != NULL) {
            _variant_t v(user->getFirstName()->c_str());
            LOGGER << _T(" Updating property FIRSTNAME->") << V_BSTR(&v) ;
            pNuser->Put(L"FIRSTNAME", 0, &v, 0);
        }

        if (user->getLastName() != NULL) {
        _variant_t v(user->getLastName()->c_str());
        LOGGER <<_T(" Updating property LASTNAME->")<< V_BSTR(&v) ;
        pNuser->Put(L"LASTNAME", 0, &v, 0);
        }

        LOGGER << _T(" Persisting My_Class information");

        IWbemCallResult *pCallRes;
        hRes = pWbemServices->PutInstance(pNuser, WBEM_FLAG_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, NULL, &pCallRes);
        if (FAILED(hRes)) {
          LOGGER << _T(" Persisting of the My_Class object failed.");
          return false;
        }

        _variant_t vnt = NULL;
        IWbemClassObject *objPtr = NULL;
        LOGGER << _T(" calling ->GetResultObject()");
        hRes = pCallRes->GetResultObject(WBEM_INFINITE, &objPtr);

        if (FAILED(hRes)) {
          LOGGER << _T(" calling GetResultObject failed");
          return false;
        }

        LOGGER << _T("Calling ->Get(ID) on instance retrieved from GetResultObject.");
        try {
          // This line gets executed before entering catch(...)
          hRes = objPtr->Get(L"ID", 0, &vnt, NULL, NULL);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& ex) {
          LOGGER << _T(" problem with Get") << ex.what();
        }
        catch (...) { // I'm entering this catch block.
          LOGGER << _T(" unknown exception...............");
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows everything you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by changing

```
hRes = pCallRes->GetResultObject(WBEM_INFINITE, &objPtr);
```

to

```
BSTR objPath = NULL;
hRes = pCallRes->GetResultString(WBEM_INFINITE, &objPath);
...
hRes = pWbemServices->GetObject(objPath, 0, NULL, &objPtr, NULL);
```

which made `vnt` in

```
hRes = objPtr->Get(L"ID", 0, &vnt, NULL, NULL);
```

not be `0`.

It appears that there was some processing being done on the instance before it was actually persisted, so the `result object` that was being retrieved wasn't "ready". When I `GetResultString` and re-get the object based on that object path, it had the values available in it. Go figure.